# Python metaclasses confusion

Tags: python

I am a bit confused regarding metaclasses in case of multiple inheritance.

Consider the following code:

```
class MetaClass1(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print "MetaClass1"

class MetaClass2(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print "MetaClass2"

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass1


class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass2

class C(A, B):
    pass
```

The output of this will be the following:

1. "MetaClass1"
2. "MetaClass2"
3. TypeError regarding metaclass conflict, which is expected, no problems regarding this.

Next I will change the code a bit and do the following:

```
class MetaClass1(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print "MetaClass1"

class MetaClass2(MetaClass1):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        print "MetaClass2 inherits"
        super(MetaClass2, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict_)

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass1


class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClass2

class C(A, B):
    pass
```

This time the output is going to be:

1. "MetaClass1"
2. "MetaClass2 inherits"

   "MetaClass1"
3. "MetaClass2 inherits"

   "MetaClass1"

The MRO of class C is:

```
[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <type 'object'>]
```

Why does class C receive MetaClass2 as its metaclass and not MetaClass1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When deciding the metaclass of a class without an explicitly specified one, as in the case of your `C`, Python examines the metaclasses of all the superclasses (direct and indirect) of the class being created, and picks the one metaclass which is a subtype of all the metaclasses of the superclasses of the class being created. If there is no such metaclass, it raises a `TypeError`.

In your example, `MetaClass2` is that one metaclass which inherits from all the metaclasses of `C`'s superclasses.

This is covered in [section 3.3.3.1](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass) of the language reference.

Comment: Thanks!
This is actually a pretty clever mechanism right there.